# how to make django tempory list?

Tags: python, django

I want to know that is it have way to make a tempory list that it can add by input field and not save to server until click some button like add to cart button. I will use this for POS system.!
[example similar to this]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvKf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django comes with [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) which might helps you.

You can use sessions or cookies to store data, both methods have a default WizardView that takes care of storing the data for you.